# Parameters from URL using Java and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, url

I am using Java and spring boot and I need to get information by a URL and store it in my class in Java. My URL is like this one

> localhost:8080/send?adress=example

I want to store the value of the URL parameter to a variable in Java.

Comment: There are tutorials on spring boot that cover this stuff...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading tutorials on spring boot and web services such as this one:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

The [RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation is used to bind method parameters to web request parameters. e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/send", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String method(@RequestParam(value="address") String address) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, that was exactly what i need

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to send a parameter with the URL, it should be sent through request parameters.

Once you have added a parameter with the request, in spring-boot by `@RequestParam` we can get parameter values. e.g

```
@RequestMapping(value="/order/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String method(@RequestParam(value="orderNumber") String orderNumber) {
    get Order by orderNumber...
}
```